# Forcing WiX Burn bootstrapper to allow MSI files to use REINSTALLMODE=amus

Tags: wix, burn

Since I wasn't a part of my company when our build process was designed and implemented (and has been successful for quite a few years now), I found out that there were things that were being done that may be looked at as 'hacks' to MSI 'purists'. However, in order to get a workable installer with [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012), I've been doing the best I can to mimic what was being done with the `.vdproj` files in [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010). Of the many snags I've hit, this one seems to be the last one that I can't resolve.

As part of our build process with Visual Studio 2010, we built our code and created a Framework MSI on one VM. Then we took that Framework MSI and installed it on a different VM. After the framework had been installed, we built our product code and created a Product MSI off of it. This created a Product dependence on our Framework. What this meant was that when installing on a client machine, the bootstrapper needed to install the Framework first followed by the Product. On uninstall our documentation stated to either have it handled through ARP or by command line '`msiexec /x {Product.msi/@ProductCode}`' and then the '`msiexec /x {Framework.msi/@ProductCode}`'.

At the time, management determined that the `ProductCode` would be the easiest way for other product teams to determine if our product had been installed on a machine. This lead them to the decision that they needed to keep a static `ProductCode` for both the Framework and the Product.

In order to handle upgrades, they had to create a `ProductTool.exe` that was nothing more than the msiexec wrapped in an executable that took a `/ProductCode={@ProductCode}` argument.

As part of our bootstrapper, they called:

- Install prerequisites ([Windows Installer 4.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer#Versions), .NET 3.5 SP1, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, [Sync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Sync_Framework) 2.1)
- `ProductTool.exe` (`Product.msi` -- to uninstall the Product.msi)
- `ProductTool.exe` (`Framework.msi` -- to uninstall the Framework.msi)
- Install `Framework.msi`
- Install `Product.msi`

However, I didn't discover until just recently that the [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) bootstrapper does not allow `REINSTALLMODE=amus`. In the install logs, it says that it changes it to `REINSTALLMODE=vomus`. Apparently in order to get that aforementioned process to work on upgrades, they had to set `REINSTALLMODE=amus`.

**UPDATE**: I finally got to talk to the original developer of the installer and found out that `REINSTALLMODE=amus` was used intentionally to revert all of the versioned files (assemblies, DLL files, etc.) and non-versioned files (.config, SQL script, etc.) as a risk minimization and robustness/"self-healing" strategy.

Having said all of that, is it even possible with a standard burn bootstrap application (BA) to set `REINSTALLMODE=amus` so that I can get the upgrades working? The MSI files have the Property's set, but Burn seems to override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not supported by the Burn engine today. Burn controls the `REINSTALLMODE` very carefully to correctly handle upgrades and repairs. Using `a` in `REINSTALLMODE` is far from a best practice and thus is not supported. Also, it isn't clear why `a` is necessary in the scenario you described.

Comment: Shouldn't we have the option to change this, though? I understand it's risky, but right now, I have a project I'm working on that needs Repair to actually repair-all, not just default repair. So since WiX apparently forbids this, what am I supposed to do? Implement a hack?