# WiX: Use Burn to recache broken MSI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

We have a busted MSI in production that needs to be fixed via `msiexec /fv package.msi` before it can be properly upgraded.

I was hopeful that we could wrap this procedure in Burn but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16860266) Q and response from Rob appears that it might not be possible.

I tried:

```
<Chain>
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="fixed-package.msi">
    <MsiProperty Name="REINSTALLMODE" Value="v"/>
  </MsiPackage>
</Chain>
```

But nothing happened.

I only need `REINSTALLMODE=v` and not `REINSTALLMODE=amus` as mentioned in the linked question, so I'm not sure if that makes a difference. The broken package has bad conditions that prevents uninstall and upgrades and this new one fixes that.

Have things changed in Burn since May '13 that recaching an existing MSI is now possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a custom action. Just have the MSI extracted as temporary file in the beginning of the install for the new version, then execute a custom action to recache it, after which continue the installation. This is how I have done it so far.

However, I don't know if Wix has support for [temporary files like Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/temp-files.html) does (which is our tool), so you might need to build a custom action for that too.